# How can I check if strings in one dataset are present in another one and add the missing values in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, match

I want to check if some strings in one `data_frame` are present in a index dataframe, if it is not, I want to add it and put 0 for the empty columns. I suppose it should be quite simple with `%in%` but I am struggling to combine it with other functions.

Imagine I have these two dfs, `ls` has all the possible values from the column `A` and `B`. On the other hand, `df` is the dataframe I want to add rows to become complete, so for every row with unique `ID` and `S` at the same time, it will be included all the possible `A` and `B` values.

Example of dfs:

```
ls <- data.frame(A = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "XYZ", "JKL"),
             B = c("KLM","MNO","", "", ""))

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,2),
             S = c("x","y","z"),
             A = c("ABC","DEF","XYZ"), 
             B = c("KLM","MNO","MNO"), 
             C = c("100","150","2"))
```

```
ls                      
+-----+-----+
|  A  |  B  |
+-----+-----+
| ABC | KLM |
| DEF | MNO |
| GHI |     |
| XYZ |     |
| JKL |     |
+-----+-----+

df
+----+---+-----+-----+-----+
| ID | S |  A  |  B  |  C  |
+----+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  1 | x | ABC | KLM | 100 |
|  2 | y | DEF | MNO | 150 |
|  2 | z | XYZ | MNO |   2 |
+----+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

From those two data sets, I want to search if `A` from `df` is present in `A` in `ls` for each unique pair of `ID` and `S`. For the pairs who are incomplete, the `A` from `ls` will be added.
So, the output data_frame would be something like this:

```
+----+---+-----+-----+-----+
| ID | S |  A  |  B  |  C  |
+----+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  1 | x | ABC | KLM | 100 |
|  1 | x | ABC | MNO |   0 |
|  1 | x | DEF | KLM |   0 |
|  1 | x | DEF | MNO |   0 |
|  1 | x | GHI | KLM |   0 |
|  1 | x | GHI | MNO |   0 |
|  1 | x | XYZ | KLM |   0 |
|  1 | x | XYZ | MNO |   0 |
|  1 | x | JKL | KLM |   0 |
|  1 | x | JKL | MNO |   0 |
|  2 | y | ABC | KLM |   0 |
|  2 | y | ABC | MNO |   0 |
|  2 | y | DEF | KLM |   0 |
|  2 | y | DEF | MNO | 150 |
|  2 | y | GHI | KLM |   0 |
|  2 | y | GHI | MNO |   0 |
|  2 | y | XYZ | KLM |   0 |
|  2 | y | XYZ | MNO |   0 |
|  2 | y | JKL | KLM |   0 |
|  2 | y | JKL | MNO |   0 |
|  2 | z | ABC | KLM |   0 |
|  2 | z | ABC | MNO |   0 |
|  2 | z | DEF | KLM |   0 |
|  2 | z | DEF | MNO |   0 |
|  2 | z | GHI | KLM |   0 |
|  2 | z | GHI | MNO |   0 |
|  2 | z | XYZ | KLM |   0 |
|  2 | z | XYZ | MNO |   2 |
|  2 | z | JKL | KLM |   0 |
|  2 | z | JKL | MNO |   0 |
+----+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

So far, I was trying something with `group_by` and `add_row`:

```
df %>% group_by(ID, S) %>% 
  ifelse(ls$A %in% df$A & ls$B %in% df$B, "",add_row(ID = df$ID,
                                      S = df$S,
                                      A = ls$A,
                                      B = ls$B,
                                      C = 0))
```

I am not sure if I am in the right path, I would be happy if someone could enlighten me on this.

Edit*
My real dataframes are like this:

```
> str(vj)
'data.frame':   2123 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ ID         : chr  "E11" "E11" "E11" "E11" ...
 $ Specificity: chr  "DP" "PostF" "DP" "DP" ...
 $ V_gene     : chr  "IGHV5-15" "IGHV2-NGC5" "IGHV5-157" "IGHV3-122" ...
 $ J_gene     : chr  "IGHJ4-3" "IGHJ4-3" "IGHJ4-3" "IGHJ4-3" ...
 $ Size       : num  664 533 369 282 273 205 200 175 164 163 ...

> str(ls)
'data.frame':   96 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V_gene: chr  "IGHV1-124" "IGHV1-138" "IGHV1-170" "IGHV1-58" ...
 $ J_gene: chr  "IGHJ1-1" "IGHJ2-1" "IGHJ3-2" "IGHJ4-3" ...

> head(vj)
   ID Specificity     V_gene  J_gene Size
1 E11          DP   IGHV5-15 IGHJ4-3  664
2 E11       PostF IGHV2-NGC5 IGHJ4-3  533
3 E11          DP  IGHV5-157 IGHJ4-3  369
4 E11          DP  IGHV3-122 IGHJ4-3  282
5 E11        PreF   IGHV3-76 IGHJ2-1  273
6 E11          DP   IGHV3-76 IGHJ4-3  205

> head(ls)
      V_gene  J_gene
1  IGHV1-124 IGHJ1-1
2  IGHV1-138 IGHJ2-1
3  IGHV1-170 IGHJ3-2
4   IGHV1-58 IGHJ4-3
5   IGHV1-84 IGHJ5-4
6 IGHV1-NGC1 IGHJ5-5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `complete` and `fill` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  complete(S, A = unique(ls$A), B = unique(ls$B), fill = list(C = 0)) %>%
  group_by(S) %>%
  fill(ID, .direction = "downup")
```

Comment: For some reason, in my original data.frame is not working as it should. I added the `str` and `head` of it. The output should have every possible combination of `A` (V_gene) and `B` (J_gene) for all the `ID` with the same `S` (Specificity).

Comment: @rodrigarco Can you check `ls`? The `ls` which you have shown is different from `ls` that you have shared with code. There is no "JKL" in the shown `ls`. Can you correct that and include expected output considering that?

Comment: @rodrigarco Can you try using `unique` over `B` as well. In the example shared all the values of `B` are already present so I did not do it there. Maybe it is not the case in your real dataset. See updated answer. I hope you don't have empty values (`""`) in your actual data.

Comment: I used `na.omit` to avoid that. Your code was very helpful, I just had to adjust to my real data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expand.grid`, `cbind` and `mutate`.  The code below should give you some direction.  I am sure there are shorter ways to do it, but this gives you step-wise approach to understand each step.

```
ls <- data.frame(A = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "XYZ"),
                 B = c("KLM","MNO","", ""))

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,2),
                 S = c("x","y","z"),
                 A = c("ABC","DEF","XYZ"), 
                 B = c("KLM","MNO","MNO"), 
                 C = c("100","150","2"))

lsb <- subset(ls,ls$B != "")
ls2 <- expand.grid(S=df$S, A=ls$A, B=lsb$B)
ls3 <- expand.grid(ID=df$ID, A=ls$A, B=lsb$B)
ls4 <- cbind(ID=ls3$ID,ls2)

lsa <- mutate(ls4, C=ifelse((ls4$ID==df$ID & ls4$S==df$S & ls4$A==df$A & ls4$B==df$B) , df$C, 0))
lsa 

> lsa
   ID S   A   B   C
1   1 x ABC KLM 100
2   2 y ABC KLM   0
3   2 z ABC KLM   0
4   1 x DEF KLM   0
5   2 y DEF KLM   0
6   2 z DEF KLM   0
7   1 x GHI KLM   0
8   2 y GHI KLM   0
9   2 z GHI KLM   0
10  1 x XYZ KLM   0
11  2 y XYZ KLM   0
12  2 z XYZ KLM   0
13  1 x ABC MNO   0
14  2 y ABC MNO   0
15  2 z ABC MNO   0
16  1 x DEF MNO   0
17  2 y DEF MNO 150
18  2 z DEF MNO   0
19  1 x GHI MNO   0
20  2 y GHI MNO   0
21  2 z GHI MNO   0
22  1 x XYZ MNO   0
23  2 y XYZ MNO   0
24  2 z XYZ MNO   2
```

Comment: The thing is that your code requires a bunch of processing, I tried to use in my real dataset or in larger things and it was too slow, thus unfeasible to be used for big data.

Comment: For big data, you should go with data.table approach.